# Update table value by adding from other table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can you please help me out with the below issue?

I have a table like below.

**Table-1**

```
Sales_RepID--                Name--           Products_Count

   1--                        ABC--                   2

   2--                        XYZ--                   4

   3--                        XXX--                   3
```

**Table-2**

```
Order_ID--  Sales_RepID--   Products_Count

1001--               2  --              2

1002--               1  --              1

1003--               2  --          1

1004--               3  --          3

1005--               2  --              2
```

**Table - 1 Result**

```
Sales_RepID,    --Name, --Products_Count

1-- ABC --3

2-- XYZ --9

3-- XXX --6
```

I want to add table-2 **Products_Count** to Table-1 **Products_Count** for each Sale_RepID in the **table-1**

Can you please help with SQL Query?

My database is MS SQL SERVER

Comment: Which is your database? MS SQL Server, Oracle, MySql etc.?

Comment: My data base is MS SQL SERVER

Answer (score 0):

For MS SQL Server, please try:

```
UPDATE T
SET T.Products_Count=T.Products_Count+x.VSum
FROM Table1 T JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        Sales_RepID, 
        SUM(Products_Count) OVER (PARTITION BY Sales_RepID) VSum 
    FROM 
        Table2
)x ON T.Sales_RepID=x.Sales_RepID
```

Comment: Hi Techdo Thank you for your reply. I tried the way you have suggested. The query is executing successfully with out any errors. But it is not updating any thing in the table. Can you please suggest any thing.

Comment: Which is your database server?

Comment: My data base is MS SQL SERVER

Answer (score 0):

To output as a select:

```
select
    t1.Sales_RepID,
    t1.Name,
    t1.Products_Count + sum(t2.Products_Count)
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t2.Sales_RepID = t1.Sales_RepID
```

To update the total in table1, adding the total from table2:

```
update table1 set
Products_Count = Products_Count + (
    select sum(Products_Count)
    from table2
    where Sales_RepID = table1.Sales_RepID)
```

These queries will work in all SQL dialects.

MS SQL Server has a special syntax for updating using a join, which will perform much better than the universal update syntax above:

```
update t1 set
t1.Products_Count = t1.Products_Count + t2.Products_Count
from table1 t1
join (select Sales_RepID, sum(Products_Count) Products_Count
      from table2
      group by Sales_RepID) t2
      on t2.Sales_RepID = t1.Sales_RepID;
```

See a [live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ab356/1) of this update statement executing on SQLFiddle.

---

Note that this is an unusual query. Typically, such [denormalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) values are *not* cumulative: they are a determinable calculated value, which in this case wold be simply the sum, not the existing value *plus* the sum. Your design means that the query can only be executed once. After than you'll be repeatedly re-adding the total from table2.

Consider redesigning your tables to have the straight sum from table2 in table1, ie:

```
update t1 set
t1.Products_Count = t2.Products_Count
from table1 t1
join (select Sales_RepID, sum(Products_Count) Products_Count
      from table2
      group by Sales_RepID) t2
      on t2.Sales_RepID = t1.Sales_RepID;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table table1(sales_repId int,name varchar(10),product_count int);
create table table2(order_id int,sales_repId int,product_count int);


insert into table1 values(1,'ABC',2);
insert into table1 values(2,'XYZ',4);
insert into table1 values(3,'XXX',3);



insert into table2 values(1001,2,2);
insert into table2 values(1002,1,1);
insert into table2 values(1003,2,1);
insert into table2 values(1004,3,3);
insert into table2 values(1005,2,2);



select a.sales_repid,name,a.product_count+sum(b.product_count)
      from table1 a 
      inner join table2 b
      on a.sales_repid=b.sales_repid
group by  a.sales_repid,name,a.product_count
order by a.sales_repid
```

**UPDATE**

```
update table1
set product_count =  netProduct
from (
select a.sales_repid,name,a.product_count+sum(b.product_count) as netProduct
      from table1 a 
      inner join table2 b
      on a.sales_repid=b.sales_repid
group by  a.sales_repid,name,a.product_count
) z
inner join table1 x
on z.sales_repid=x.sales_repid
```

Comment: Hi..Ca you please provide me with a update statement...I want to update the values in table-1

Comment: Hi Mhasan, Thank you for trhe reply. I tried the way you suggested, But its not working. Is it such a complecated to update a table by adding value from other table??

Comment: hahahaha...bhai mey bhi bas andherey me teer chala raha hun..definitely there would be some simple method....

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS

```
DECLARE @TABLE1 AS TABLE( Sales_RepID INT,Name   VARCHAR(100), Products_Count int)
DECLARE @TABLE2 AS TABLE( Order_ID INT,Sales_RepID INT, Products_Count int)

INSERT INTO @TABLE1
VALUES(1,'ABC',2),(2,'XYZ',4),(3,'XXX',3)


INSERT INTO @TABLE2
VALUES(1001,2,2),(1002,1,1),(1003,2,1),(1004,3,3),(1005,2,2)

SELECT * FROM @TABLE1
SELECT * FROM @TABLE2

UPDATE T1
SET     T1.Products_Count = T1.Products_count + total
FROM @TABLE1 T1
CROSS APPLY (
SELECT total= sum(Products_count)
FROM @Table2 T2
WHERE T1.Sales_RepID =t2.Sales_RepID ) Z
```